# Android ICS browser is not displaying png image

Tags: android, html, image, png

In a phonegap html5 application, we are using [`tadataurl.js`](https://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/) plugin in order to use the canvas element in older versions of Android (2.3.x).
The images are saved on our server, but for some reason its not displayed in Android ICS (4.0.3).
Other versions of Android, iphones, and chrome (desktop) are displaying it properly.

Anyone knows why this image below is not displayed only on Android ICS?

http://remini.my.phpcloud.com//example.png

Comment: i found this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1866363 but not solved

Comment: double slash in the url maybe?

Comment: The link to example.png seems to be dead.